# Waiting for missing types to be registered:

Tags: embedded-linux, node-red

I'm trying to run node-red on a Moxa UC8112, which has no graphics whatsoever and run completely through SSH command line.

I have tried to register and fix the node_modules with "npm install request" and "npm audit fix", but still receive the "Waiting for missing types to be registered:" error.

My command prompt is as follows:

```
moxa@Moxa:~/.node-red$
moxa@Moxa:~/.node-red$ npm install request
+ request@2.88.0
updated 1 package and audited 387 packages in 85.818s
found 0 vulnerabilities

moxa@Moxa:~/.node-red$ npm audit fix
up to date in 48.031s
fixed 0 of 0 vulnerabilities in 387 scanned packages
moxa@Moxa:~/.node-red$ node-red
31 Jan 11:47:40 - [info]

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

31 Jan 11:47:40 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.19.5
31 Jan 11:47:40 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.14.0
31 Jan 11:47:40 - [info] Linux 4.1.0-ltsi-rt-uc8100-me+ arm LE
31 Jan 11:47:45 - [info] Loading palette nodes
31 Jan 11:47:50 - [warn] rpi-gpio : Raspberry Pi specific node set inactive
31 Jan 11:47:50 - [warn] rpi-gpio : Cannot find Pi RPi.GPIO python library
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info] Settings file  : /home/moxa/.node-red/settings.js
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info] User directory : /home/moxa/.node-red
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [warn] Projects disabled :     
editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info] Flows file     : /home/moxa/.node-        red/flows_Moxa.json
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [warn]

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.

If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.

You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------

31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - twilioConfig
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - modbustcp-server
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - twilio-api
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - modbus-client
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - amazon config
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - sms
31 Jan 11:48:02 - [info]  - modbus-getter
```

I expect it to be an issue possibly with how I installed the node_modules? Even though I made sure to "npm install " in the .node-red directory.

Comment: Please edit the question to add more details, how did you create the flow you are trying run? You need to install the missing Node-RED nodes (request is not a Node-RED node), you can do this via the manage pallet option

Comment: I created the flow on my desktop and then used a SFTP software called WinSCP to move the flow file over to the embedded computer.

Answer (score 3):

In order to move a flow from one instance of Node-RED to another you need to ensure that all the nodes used are installed on the target system.

You can either install them via the manage pallet option in the menu or with npm on the command line.

The easiest way is probably to copy the `package.json` file from the .node-red directory on the source system to the . node-red directory on the target and then run `npm install` while in the same directory.